# How do you use your iPod shuffle or nano?

Tags: ipod-nano, ipod-shuffle

I bought my first Apple product a few months ago, an iPod shuffle, a tiny little music gadget that's fun to play with. However its getting a little boring because I don't know what I can do with it or places I can use it. Currently, I'm limited to listening to it during sleeptime as a lullaby machine. What do *you* do with your iPod shuffle/nano? how do you get the most out of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nanos or shuffles are great for workouts at the gym or while running. You can use them just about anywhere. I personally use a Classic for my stuff, but the nano is great if you have a smaller library or want something very mobile.

As far as what you can do with it (other than playing music), it really depends on which generation you have. You obviously can't really run 'apps' on it, but many generations (of nanos) had some small games, radios, could play video, etc.

Answer (score 2):

My shuffle has two playlists:

- Sleep: Thirty minutes of soft instrumental music followed by nine hours of rainfall
- Wakeup: One hour of four- and five-star songs lasting two to five minutes that have not been played in the past six months

It needs a recharge every two days.

Answer (score 1):

I use my iPod nano in the car to listen to podcasts during my commute. I have a [Belkin TuneBase FM Transmitter](http://amzn.com/B000WW1YVU)—the older model of what's shown below—so that I can listen using my car's stereo.

[image: Belkin TuneBase FM Transmitter]

Answer (score 1):

On my iPod Shuffle (Gen 3) I have one playlist, "Gym" - mainly fast paced rock and electronic music, I use this while I'm training. The shuffle is ideal for this as it is lightweight and clips to my gym kit unobtrusively.

That is all I use it for as have an iPhone, so use that as my day to day device, however, even the 2GB Shuffle will hold 12 hours of music if you want to listen to it at work etc, although I appreciate it is a bit trickier to navigate music.

Answer (score 0):

I use may 6th gen nano (the touchscreen one) as a pedometer and a flashlight when my iPod touch runs out of battery. (Also as practice for iOS accessibility gestures.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a long commute to and from work and I find that whether I am in the walking part of the commute or the part that involves buses and trains, it helps me relax, pass time faster or wake up better depending on the tracks I decide to play.

If I'm at home and want to work on artistic projects, it's also great to use in conjunction with speakers (I use a Bose SoundLink mini).

Once I played music while taking a bath it was really nice.

Based on how many songs play, you can know exactly how much time passed. Just try to remember the name of the first and last song, and when you're near your computer plug it to iTunes and click from the first to the last song and the total duration will be displayed.